# Adding brackets in specific position R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm working on a data frame containing information about municipalities and its respective states like below:

```
Municipality <- c('Ariquemes', 'Borba', 'Bagre')
State <- c('RO', 'AM', 'PA')
df <- data.frame(Municipality, State)
```

I used the function `paste` to create a new column containing both the municipality and state names:

```
df$Municipality_State<-paste(df$Municipality, df$State)
df>
Municipality     State     Municipality State
Ariquemes        RO        Ariquemes PA
Borba            AM        Borba AM
Bagre            PA        Bagre PA
```

Now, I'd like to add brackets around the State name to merge with another database i'm working on. The output I'm looking for is like:

```
 Municipality     State     Municipality_State
    Ariquemes        RO        Ariquemes (PA)
     Borba            AM        Borba (AM)
     Bagre            PA        Bagre (PA)
```

I would appreciate your comments
Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without making it too complicated, we can add brackets while pasting the columns.

```
df$Municipality_State <- paste0(df$Municipality, " (", df$State, ")")

df
#  Municipality State Municipality_State
#1    Ariquemes    RO     Ariquemes (RO)
#2        Borba    AM         Borba (AM)
#3        Bagre    PA         Bagre (PA)
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution @Ronak. Your code deleted the state names that should be inside the brackets.

Comment: @phill_9933 Sorry, I didn't get you. You did not get the output as shown in my answer? Isn't that your expected output?

Comment: Not really, @Ronak Shah. In the first line, for example, I got: #1 Ariquemes  |  RO  |  Ariquemes ( )

Comment: I'm sorry, @Ronak Shah. Your code is right! I made a mistake when copied your code to my Console. Really sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sprintf`

```
df$Municipality_State <- sprintf("%s (%s)", df$Municipality, df$State)
```